# Push doesn't modify the list being a function argument

Tags: arguments, parameter-passing, common-lisp, mutable, sbcl

I'm new to common lisp, so hope someone would clarify this to me:

say we have a list and want to add an item with `push` to modify it:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter xx '(1 2 3))
XX
CL-USER> xx
(1 2 3)
CL-USER> (push 100 xx)
(100 1 2 3)
CL-USER> xx
(100 1 2 3)
```

as expected. But when i try to do the same with the function, it doesn't modify a list:

```
CL-USER> (defun push-200 (my-list)
           (push 200 my-list))
PUSH-200
CL-USER> (push-200 xx)
(200 100 1 2 3)
CL-USER> xx
(100 1 2 3)
```

so i tried to compare argument and my list like this:

```
CL-USER> (defun push-200 (my-list)
           (format t "~a" (eq my-list xx))
           (push 200 my-list))

WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::PUSH-200 in DEFUN
PUSH-200
CL-USER> (push-200 xx)
T
(200 100 1 2 3)
CL-USER> xx
(100 1 2 3)
```

it says the objects are identical.
So the question is: what was the thing I've overlooked here?

Comment: Push isn't supposed to modify the list;  it's supposed to modify the place to update the place's value to be a new list.  The place, in this case, is a local variable, and the local variable *is* updated to hold a new list.

Comment: You may find [Common lisp push from function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396224/common-lisp-push-from-function) helpful.

Comment: Thanks! now i see the semantics, but still it looks weird to me. So it means the only way to `push` some val to list inside a function, is to modify it's `car/cdr` ? like `(let ((old-car (car my-list))) (setq (car my-list) value (cdr my-list (cons old-car (cdr my-list))))` ?

Comment: What you're asking for isn't really idiomatic in Common Lisp.  Functions that modify list structure (e.g., **delete**, **sort**) typically *return* a result, and it's up to the consumer to *use* the result.  Functions aren't usually called for destructive side-effects;  rather the side-effects are *permitted* for efficiency, but the contract ("use the result") stays the same.

Comment: Your approach to "push some val to a list inside a function" approach doesn't work;  what happens if the original list is empty?  You can't modify the car or cdr of the empty list;  it doesn't have those.  That said, if you do want to use the approach you described, you might do it a little more clearly with `(push newvalue (rest list)) (rotatef (first list) (second list))`.  (That's certainly not the only option, though.)

Comment: Thanks again. Ok, i'm aware of this style (quasi functional, i would say), just wanted to clear out the semantics. But this obviously leads me to another, more significant question: is there any proper styleguide for modern common lisp development? I mean the language is huge, and i'm always paralyzed about what solution to chose.

Comment: I don't really see this as a *style* issue; it's just one of data structures.  Aside from C/assembler where you can pass the *address* of primitive structures around, in pretty much *any* language you'll need to pass some kind of value container if you want to update the value.  E.g., in Java the List that you pass into such a function can have elements added to it because the List *encapsulates* the underlying list of values.  In Common Lisp, you could certainly do `(defstruct lyst x)` and `(defun push-200 (lyst) (push 200 (list-x lyst)))`, and get the behavior that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun push-200 (my-list)
  (push 200 my-list))
```

This modifies the variable `my-list`. The variable now points to a new *cons*.

It is basically: `(setq my-list (cons 200 my-list)`.

```
(push-200 xx)
```

Common Lisp evaluates `xx` to a value and passes the list to `push-200`. `xx` is not passed, but the value of it. So, the Lisp system can't modify `xx` to point to a different cons, since it is not passed.

Answer (score 2):

This is (essentially) the same problem highlighted by the following:

```
(let ((a (list 2 3 4 5)))
  (let ((b a))
    (push 1 a)
    (list (eql a b)
          (eql (cdr a) b))))
```

This form should return `(NIL T)` when run.

Answer (score 1):

What Rainer Joswig writes (and Vatine demonstrates). Just replace `(push <A> <B>)` with `(setq <B> (cons <A> <B>))` wherever you see it, because [`push` is a macro](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm):

> "**push** *item place => new-place-value*"

And,

> *"new-place-value [is] a list (the* new *value of place)"*

Notice CLHS didn't say *"(the updated structure referred to by place)"*.

So, the value of *place* changes. And that place, in your case, is the local variable `my-list`. It was `eq` to `xx` before the `(setq ...)`, but obviously *not*,  after it. To actually alter a list structure you can use [`rplaca`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rplaca.htm) and ⁄ or [`rplacd`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rplaca.htm).

We can think about argument passing in Common Lisp mostly as if what was passed is a pointer to a value; the pointer itself is passed *by value*, i.e. copied. So `xx` "points" at some list; and initially `my-list` "points" at the same memory location. That's why the initial `eq` test succeeds.