# Pushing new elements into a new empty list using Lisp

Tags: list, common-lisp, element

The below function tries to update `*features-list*` With the element feature. 
*feature-list* is defined as a global variable.

When I run the function against an empty `*feature-list*`,I get an error Message

```
The object is a CONDITION of type TYPE-ERROR.
DATUM: NIL
EXPECTED-TYPE: CONS
```

However, when I initialize the `*feature-list*`, the function executes properly.

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (let ((feature-index))
    (setq feature-index (position feature *features-list*))
    (cond ((equal feature-index nil) 
           (push feature (cdr (last *features-list*)))
           (setq feature-index (position feature *features-list*))))))
```

Comment: Please fix your code - indentation and parentheses. Right now is it unreadable.

Comment: yes..any idea about what can be causing the error?

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793011/push-doesnt-modify-the-list-being-a-function-argument#comment57330915_34793011).

Comment: that explains the error and provides a solution! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution provided by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793011/push-doesnt-modify-the-list-being-a-function-argument#comment57330915_34793011) from Joshua Taylor.

> Your approach to "push some val to a list inside a function" approach
>   doesn't work; what happens if the original list is empty? You can't
>   modify the car or cdr of the empty list; it doesn't have those.  That
>   said, if you do want to use the approach you described, you might do
>   it a little more clearly with `(push newvalue (rest list))` `(rotatef (first list) (second list))`. (That's certainly not the only option,
>   though.)

Answer (score 3):

Use standard formatting.  See http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code.

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (let ((feature-index))
    (setq feature-index (position feature *features-list*))
    (cond ((equal feature-index nil)
           ;;case 1 If feature index ==nil ;;we need to add the feature 
           (push feature (cdr (last *features-list*)))
           (setq feature-index (position feature *features-list*))))))
```

A `cond` with one clause is meaningless.  I guess you meant `when`, and that you
want to update the index in any case, i. e. outside of the conditional.

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (let ((feature-index))
    (setq feature-index (position feature *features-list*))
    (when (equal feature-index nil)
      (push feature (cdr (last *features-list*))))
    (setq feature-index (position feature *features-list*))))
```

You do not need to set a local variable just to return it:

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (let ((feature-index))
    (setq feature-index (position feature *features-list*))
    (when (equal feature-index nil)
      (push feature (cdr (last *features-list*))))
    (position feature *features-list*)))
```

You can create the binding directly in the `let` head:

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (let ((feature-index (position feature *features-list*)))
    (when (equal feature-index nil)
      (push feature (cdr (last *features-list*))))
    (position feature *features-list*)))
```

Instead of checking for `equal` … `nil`, use `null`:

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (let ((feature-index (position feature *features-list*)))
    (when (null feature-index)
      (push feature (cdr (last *features-list*))))
    (position feature *features-list*)))
```

You can inline that variable:

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (when (null (position feature *features-list*))
    (push feature (cdr (last *features-list*))))
  (position feature *features-list*))
```

Instead of `null` … `position`, use `not` … `member`:

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (when (not (member feature *features-list*))
    (push feature (cdr (last *features-list*))))
  (position feature *features-list*))
```

The `cdr` of the last cons in a list is not a place that you would want to push
things onto.  I guess that you want to `append`, but in most cases, you should
instead push to the front of the list, which is much more efficient.
There is also `pushnew` for exactly this.  Returning the new position does not
make much sense now, however:

```
(defun update-feature-list (feature)
  (pushnew feature *features-list*)
  (position feature *features-list*))
```

If you really need this order and the positions, use adjustable vectors instead:

```
(defvar *features-list* (make-array 10
                                    :adjustable t
                                    :fill-pointer 0))

(defun add-feature (feature)
  (or (position feature *features-list*)
      (vector-push-extend feature *features-list*))) ; v-p-e returns the index
```

Comment: thanks...however, i do need this exact order of elements..so i cannot push in the beginning of the list...i tried the above code corrections..With push as well as append..and both have the same behavior..error when the list is empty, nd proper behavior when intialized at least With one element..

Comment: so it turns out when i use append insteaad of push..and initialize the list to (defparameter *features_list* nil) instead of what i used to initialize to as (defparameter *featuteres_list* '()) it workd properly.. While using the push, the error persists as long as the list is empty independantly of how it is initialized.. for me, i am happy using the append for now for this..but if someone can explain why push behaves this way on empty lists, it would be great

Comment: @ijuio: `(push 'foo *list*)` is the same as `(setf *list* (cons 'foo *list*))`.  `(list 'a 'b 'c)` is the same as `(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c nil)))`.  That is the way lists work in Lisp: they are a cons chain.  When your variable is bound to a list, it actually refers to the "first" or "outermost" cons cell.  `Last` returns the last or "innermost" cons cell.  `Nil` is not a cons but an atom, and it is also used as the empty list.