# Can't change list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

For example, I have function `stack-push` which pushes element onto the stack.

```
(defun stack-push (stack element)
    (if (not (listp element))
        (setf stack (cons element stack))
        (dolist (current-el (reverse element))
            (setf stack (cons current-el stack)))))
```

But when I invoke it like `(stack-push *some-stack* '(a b c d e))`, it doesn't affect on `*some-stack*`. Could you explain why?

Comment: Because Lisp calls functions with the values, not the variables themselves. All your SETF does is changing the local variable `stack`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common lisp push from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396224/common-lisp-push-from-function)

Comment: Also: [Push doesn't modify the list being a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793011/push-doesnt-modify-the-list-being-a-function-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setf` with a symbol as place like `(setf stack (cons element stack))` expands to `(setq stack (cons element stack))`. This usually happens when you create your function. Your function becomes this:

```
(defun stack-push (stack element)
  (if (not (listp element)
      (setq stack (cons element stack))
      (dolist (current-el (reverse element))
        (setq stack (cons current-el stack)))))
```

Note that I have only expanded `setf` here. Both `defun` and `dolist` becomes quite horrendous expansions that makes the code more unreadable. The system expands the forms fully so the code that runs has no macros.

`setq` updates a binding so when it updates `stack` that is what it updates, not `*some-stack*`. Here is exactly what is happening if you do `(stack-push *some-stack* "a")`:

1. You pass the **function** `*some-stack*` and `"a"`. It evaluates its arguments.
2. `*some-stack*` evaluates to address A that has a `cons` cell eg. `("b")`.
3. `"a"` is a literal residing at address B
4. The parameters gets bound to new bindings. `stack` points to A and element points to B.
5. Since `element` points to B `(not (listp element)) ; ==> t` and the code follows the consequent.
6. in `(setf stack (cons element stack))` was before runtime changed to  `(setq stack (cons element stack))`.
7. `(cons element stack)` calls `cons` with B and A as arguments. returns a new cell with address C `("a" "b")`
8. `setq` updates so that binding `stack` points to C.
9. `stack-push` returns the last evaluated value, which is the result of the `setq` which is the second argument C.

In the function there is no mention of `*some-stack*`. The binding is never references or updated. Only `stack` is updates with what new value to point to.

As a consequence of this being a function you can call your function with literals, which normally would not work if the argument was a variable meant to be  updated.

```
(stack-push '("b") "a") ; ==> ("a" "b")
```

There is a form called `push`. It is **not a function**. You can see what it does:

```
(macroexpand '(push "a" *some-stack*)) 
; ==> (setq *some-stack* (cons "a" *some-stack*))
```

Thus for `push` to work you need that second argument is something `setf`-able. Trying it with literals expands to unrunnable code. For types you can make your own `setf` expander such that `setf` and `push` works.

Answer (score 2):

As a note to Sylwester's answer, here is a version of your `stack-push` which at first sight looks correct but which in fact has an ugly problem (thanks to jkiiski for pointing this out!), followed by a simpler version which still has the problem, and finally a variant of the simpler version which does not.

Here is the initial version.  This agrees with your signature (it takes either a single argument which cannot be a list, or a list of arguments, and decides what to do based on what it sees).

```
(defmacro stack-push (stack element/s)
  ;; buggy, see below!
  (let ((en (make-symbol "ELEMENT/S")))
    `(let ((,en ,element/s))
       (typecase ,en
         (list
          (setf ,stack (append (reverse ,en)
                               ,stack)))
         (t
          (setf ,stack (cons ,en ,stack)))))))
```

However I would be more tempted to write it with an `&rest` argument, as follows.  This version is simpler because it always does one thing.  It is still buggy though.

```
(defmacro stack-push* (stack &rest elements)
  ;; still buggy
  `(setf ,stack (append (reverse (list ,@elements)) ,stack)))
```

This version could be used as

```
(let ((a '()))
  (stack-push* a 1 2 3)
  (assert (equal a '(3 2 1))))
```

for instance.  And it seems like it works.

### Multiple evaluation

But it doesn't work, because it can multiply-evaluate things which should not be multiply-evaluated. The easiest way (I found) to see this is to look at what the macro expansion is.

I have a little utility function to do this, called `macropp`: this just calls `macroexpand-1` as many times as you ask for, pretty printing the result.  To see the problem you need to expand twice: first to expand `stack-push*` and then to see what happens to the resulting `seetf`.  The second expansion is implementation-dependent, but you can see the problem.  This sample is from Clozure CL which has a particularly simple expansion:

```
? (macropp '(stack-push* (foo (a)) 1) 2)
-- (stack-push* (foo (a)) 1)
-> (setf (foo (a)) (append (reverse (list 1)) (foo (a))))
-> (let ((#:g86139 (a)))
     (funcall #'(setf foo) (append (reverse (list 1)) (foo (a))) #:g86139))
```

And you can see the problem: `setf` doesn't know anything about `foo` so it's just calling `#'(setf foo)`.  It carefully makes sure that the subforms are evaluated in the right order, but it just evaluates the second subform in the obvious way, with the result that `(a)` gets evaluated *twice*, which is wrong: if it has side-effects then they will happen twice.

So the fix for this is to use `define-modify-macro` whose job is to solve this problem.  To do this, you define a function which makes the stack, and then use `define-modify-macro` to make the macro:

```
(defun stackify (s &rest elements)
  (append (reverse elements) s))

(define-modify-macro stack-push* (s &rest elements)
  stackify)
```

And now

```
? (macropp '(stack-push* (foo (a)) 1) 2)
-- (stack-push* (foo (a)) 1)
-> (let* ((#:g86170 (a)) (#:g86169 (stackify (foo #:g86170) 1)))
     (funcall #'(setf foo) #:g86169 #:g86170))
-> (let* ((#:g86170 (a)) (#:g86169 (stackify (foo #:g86170) 1)))
     (funcall #'(setf foo) #:g86169 #:g86170))
```

And you can see that now `(a)` is only evaluated once (and also that you only now need a single level of macroexpansion).

Thanks again to jkiiski for pointing out the bugs.

---

### `macropp`

For completeness, here is the function I use to pretty-print macro expansions.  This is just a hack.

```
(defun macropp (form &optional (n 1))
  (let ((*print-pretty* t))
    (loop repeat n
          for first = t then nil
          for current = (macroexpand-1 form) then (macroexpand-1 current)
          when first do (format t "~&-- ~S~%" form)
          do (format t "~&-> ~S~%" current)))
  (values))
```

Comment: You're still evaluating the place (`stack`) multiple times. It might have non-pure subforms, which would cause problems. It would be easier to write a regular function that returns the new value, and use `DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO` to make a modify macro for it.

Comment: @jkiiski I'm not as far as I can see: there are at most two occurrences of the stack (because `typecase` only evaluates one of the two cases) and only one of them is evaluated normally, the other being the first subform in `setf`.

Comment: For example, `(setf (foo (random 10)) (+ 10 (foo (random 10))))` evaluates `(random 10)` twice.

Comment: @jkiiski: oh, yes, I feel stupid now.  I've modified the answer fairly extensively (with credit).  Thanks!